# I'm not able to add a custom domain name to my Azure website

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I recently activated Azure services that came with my MSDN subscription. I created a website with it and wanted to assign a custom domain for the website. Unfortunately, the "Manage Domains" option in the website dashboard is grayed out.

Comment: You will need to increase to atleast a "Shared" Plan by using either the **Scale tab** in the [full featured portal](http://manage.windowsazure.com) or **Pricing Tier** in the [Preview Portal](http://portal.azure.com)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't add a custom domain to a free Azure website.  You have to upgrade (SCALE tab on the portal) to Shared, Basic or Standard web hosting plan mode to add a custom domain.

Comment: Wow that ramps up suddenly from "Free" to at least £70 per month! Christ!

Comment: @jamheadart take a look at Azure static web sites, very affordable with custom domain capability

Comment: Thanks for the info, it's good to know! RIght now I'm actually hosting .net core sites with SQL db, actually several asp.net core sites on one VPS for a fraction of their lowest price! I was hoping to make the move to azure but it's way too costly, I'll have to stick to current methods.